# jQuery If/Else If not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this code:

```
$("#Editing").click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr("class","OptionsOpt-On")) 
    {$(this).attr("class","OptionsOpt-Off"); Edit = false;}

  else if ($(this).attr("class","OptionsOpt-Off")) 
    {$(this).attr("class","OptionsOpt-On"); Edit = true;}
});
```

I have searched and haven't been able to find a similar answer because all the ones that I found had problems with the code that I have identified to not be in my code. I don't know why the "else if" doesn't work, but if I change it to an if, it works just fine...

Answer (score 4):

[`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) with 2 arguments = setter = returns a jQuery object which is always a truthy value.

You should use it as a [getter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) and do comparison:

```
if ( $(this).attr("class") === 'OptionsOpt-On' ) {
//...
```

Though [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) may be more appropriate in this case:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('OptionsOpt-On') ) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

As your element can't have both classes at the same time, you don't need a second `if` in the `else`.

---

Also assuming the element starts with one of the classes you can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle both classes without needing a conditional statement:

```
$("#Editing").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('OptionsOpt-On OptionsOpt-Off');
    Edit = $(this).hasClass('OptionsOpt-On');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmwT7/1/)

Comment: The OP should also note that the target element has to has at least either class assigned to it before the `.click()` event, or else the if-else will not work because neither conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @Terry Yes, nicely noted. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
if ($(this).attr("class")=="OptionsOpt-On")
```

The `.attr` function when used with two arguments works as a setter, while as a getter with just one argument.